# Commands inside bash not being interpreted?

Tags: shell, sed, quoting, command-substitution

I'm trying to execute a command inside a bash script, **$(pwd)** is not being interpreted at all, and not even using eval.

This do not work:

```
cat apache-vhost.conf | sed 's/{path}/$(pwd)/g'
```

Neither does this:

```
eval cat apache-vhost.conf | sed 's/{path}/$(pwd)/g'
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Just an FYI, that's _not_ a bash script, it's a `sed` command and that has nothing to do with `bash` or any other shell any more than `ls` does.

Comment: It's a sed command inside a bash script. But indeed not a bash related question.

Comment: Oh, if there's a bash script, please include it. It's not the case here, but in general, the details often depend on the way you're calling the command. As it stands, the only shell (not specific to bash) feature here is the `|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using single quotes in your `sed` expression which would prevent variable expansion.  Use double quotes.  Moreover, use a different separator than `/`:

```
sed "s|{path}|$(pwd)|g" apache-vhost.conf
```

Moreover, `cat file | sed` is a useless use of `cat`.

Comment: sed "s/{path}/$(pwd)/g" file << This does not work as well.

Comment: It's true the command needs to be inside double quotes, thought only PHP had that. But unfortunately it's still not working, something to do with sed maybe.

Comment: @user1091856 Use a different separator.  See the edit.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Don't know why the different separator, but it worked.

Comment: @user1091856 If the pattern or replacement contain `/`, then you need a different separator or you need to escape the `/` in the pattern & replacement.